# open share from safari IOS - javascript

Tags: javascript

good day, I have a JavaScript script that when opening it from the safari browser on any iPhone opens the option to share but I don't get the option within the share to "add to start" which is what I need, sent my code of what I have, if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

```html
<script>
var nativeShare = function() {
   if (navigator.share) { 
      navigator.share({
         title: "titulo",
         text: "texto",
         url: "URL", 
      }) 
   }
   return false;
}
</script>
HTML

   <button onclick="return nativeShare();">
   compartir </button>
Ejemplo
```

Comment: "Add to Start" is not an option in iOS - did you mean "Add to Home Screen"?

Comment: Also, MDN's documentation for `Navigator.share` says it's only functional in _secure contexts_ (i.e. `https://`, not `http://`). Please confirm your page is running in a secure-context or not.

Comment: Also, `navigator.share` returns a `Promise`, but you aren't using the `await` operator on it (or using `.then().catch()`).

Comment: If my page is entering with https:, could you accommodate my code so that it works.